# Openlayers 3 - how to get id/index ol.geom.LineString vertex by coordinates

Tags: openlayers, linestring

I'm having a list of points (coordinates + extra info). I want to show them on the map as LineString and when I hover a vertex/point I want to get a callback where I display extra info for the given point. As the list could be big I don't want to create a feature for each point, but just one for the LineString. Otherwise I end up in performance problems.
I can easily take the closest point from the LineString, but it's just coordinates, without any identification ... index would be sufficient.

Here is how my code looks like:

```
var geometry = new ol.geom.LineString(positions);
map.on("pointermove", function(event)
{
    if (event.dragging) { return; }

    var mouseCoordinates = map.getEventCoordinate(event.originalEvent);
    var closestPoint = geometry.getClosestPoint(mouseCoordinates);
    console.log(closestPoint);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to do that. But I'm still not sure if it's OK or it's a workaround. When building the LineString you can pass a layout which is responsible for the point format (XY, XYZ, XYM, XYZM). As far as I was able to understand from [OpenLayers3 Docs](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.geom.html#.GeometryLayout) 'M' stands for measure.
So, I'm using XYM layout, populating the points with index and then the closest point returns that as well:

```
var positions = myData.map(function (item, index) { return [item.Longitude, item.Latitude, index]; });
var geometry = new ol.geom.MultiLineString([positions], "XYM");

... later in the pointermove event:
var coordinate = this.map.getEventCoordinate(event.originalEvent);
var point = geometry.getClosestPoint(coordinate);

// point[2] is estimation of the index.
// For example 23.765 is a position between points 23 and 24. Closer to 24.
console.log(point[2]);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind it shouldn't be id or index, there's a way to get features where's your mouse pointer on.

```
var geometry = new ol.geom.LineString(positions);
map.on("pointermove", function(event) {
    if (event.dragging) { return; }
    var features = [];

    map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(event.pixel, function(feature, layer) {
        features.push(feature);
    });

    // features: features under your mouse pointer
});
```

Comment: The problem is that I'm loading too many points (let's say 500k+). When I load them as one LineString - everything is fine. But when I load each point as a feature the memory and CPU are gone. So, I need to know which vertex did the user hovered, not which feature.